# How to allow data selection across multiple entry widgets in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, clipboard

I am currently using a table, with cells comprised of entry widgets, I would like to allow the user to select across the cells, like you would in a table or Excel.

The blank column is just an entry widget with the state value set to disabled, this is just a spacer i could put a frame or something else here.

I have looked into tkinter table but I am using python3 and as far as I can tell it doesn't work with python3:

[image: http://i101.photobucket.com/albums/m58/timeyyy_da_man/table_screenshot.png]

just to be clear for the first row, I would like the user to be able to drag across and select 123, and then 456 all in the one go. Also how would I go about getting the data to paste into other tables?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution to this, it will require a fair amount of code. You will have to create custom bindings for button presses and releases, and for dragging across multiple widgets. I don't think it is impossible, but it will be difficult to get right.

If you go down this path, you will need to set the `exportselection` attribute of each entry to false so that the selection in all widgets will be visible.

Comment: Thanks mate, i will give it a go and report back on my findings.